# Multiple Outstanding Pull Requests

Tags: git, github

I have a project hosted on github that currently has a number of outstanding pull requests that I wish to merge. Are there any 'best practices' here, things I should be aware of? For example, if I merge request A, does that mean request B is now out of sync?

The outstanding pull requests mainly target separate functionality i.e. different sections of the code, but a couple of the requests do make additions over multiple lines both at the mid and end sections of a single file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some best practice from the docs you can use: https://github.community/t5/Support-Protips/Best-practices-for-pull-requests/ba-p/4104.

When you merge request A, you may not experience a merge conflict when you try to merge request B especially, if those changes are in different files. If changes are in the same file, then you might need to sort the merge conflicts. Depending on the changes, it might not be that difficult and can be fixed right on GitHub.

Please use these links below to understand better.
https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges

https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/merging-a-pull-request